# Excel Bar chart hide #N/A rows without VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, charts

In Excel, I have two columns:

[image]

When I plot a bar chart, I get the following:

[image]

How can I hide the #N/A values?

The #N/A are generated using NA()

I've created a Name in Name Manager for column T:

```
=OFFSET(Daily!$T$2,0,0,COUNTA(Daily!$T:$T)-1)
```

I use this Name in chart series

I don't prefer to use VBA

Comment: The easiest method is,, select and Right click any of line/bar, and hit Select data,, then in left box you find series,,, un check those series has #N/A or blank (you need to count them) & finish with OK

Comment: @RajeshS That does not help.

Comment: could u please share the workbook through Drop Box & let me examine .

Comment: Once try this,, Click on line on chart,, Right click on the series with a break, and choose Select Data, Click hidden and empty cells, Check zero, and then press Ok.

Comment: change your named range to fit the set you want ie. use countif not counta, and count the number of cells that do not contain #N/A